# Trying to revert back to older version of commit

Tags: git, github

Current I am working on a  project and I have plenty of commits on my github. The commit sequence maybe like this:

### A -> B -> C -> D -> E

After working on for a while, I realize that I have done big mistake on later progress and I wish to rollback to B. How can I revert back to B and delete C, D and E?

Comment: You might want to check this out: https://help.github.com/en/desktop/contributing-to-projects/reverting-a-commit

Answer (score 0):

You should do a `git log` and copy the commit hash of `B` and then do `git reset <commit hash you just copied>`. Note that this will unstage the changes made in `C`, `D` and `E`. If you are really very sure about deleting these changes use a `--hard` flag with the reset command.